# GridViewColumnHeader confusion

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

Why would that work:

```
<Style x:Key="myHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
  <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightBlue"/>
</Style>
```

And not this?

```
<ListView.View>
     <GridView>
         <GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
             <Style>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange" />
             </Style>
         </GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
...
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `TargetType` property on the Style or the parser won't know how to resolve `Background`:

```
<ListView.View>
    <GridView>
        <GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="GridViewColumnHeader">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange" />
            </Style>
        </GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
```

It's also possible to qualify the property name in the Setter:

```
<Setter Property="GridViewColumnHeader.Background" Value="Orange" />
```

but that syntax is intended for attached properties.

Comment: Thank you! It's so dumb and I didn't think of that.